# Can't find out why my program isn't doing what it's supposed to do

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

As part of the CS50 Harvard programming course, which I'm currently attending, I'm doing an exercise called "Vigenere".

My program is doing everything right (it's going line by line and the expected behavior is met) except when I receive input that starts with a `b`.

Once it reaches the end of the input string it doesn't loop back around to the first character in the array, but if the input doesn't start with a b it works like it should.

Have been googling, debugging but just can't figure it out. Have tried doing it in a lot of other different ways too but I just can't get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Error.\n");
            return (1);
        }
        string input = argv[1];

        for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if (!isalpha(input[i]))
            {
                printf("Error.\n");
                return (1);
            }
        }
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        string cipher = argv[1];
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int code = 0;

        while (plaintext[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (cipher[j] >= 97)
            {
                cipher[j] = cipher[j] - 97;
            }
            if (isupper(cipher[j]))
            {
               cipher[j] = cipher[j] - 65;
            }
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", 'a' + (plaintext[i] - 'a' + cipher[j]) % 26);
                j++;
            }
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", 'A' + (plaintext[i] - 'A' + cipher[j]) % 26);
                j++;
            }
            if (plaintext[i] == ' ')
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
            if (!isalpha(plaintext[i]) && !isspace(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
            if (cipher[j] == '\0' && plaintext[i] != ' ')
            {
                j = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return (0);
    }
```

As explained above, whenever my command line input starts with a b the program doesn't work as expected. Doesn't happen when input is not a b.

Comment: The *#include <cs50.h>* is missing, so we can't run and reproduce the problem

Comment: Please explain what it should do, what is the input and output when it works and example of input and output when it doesn’t work. It’s difficult for us to know what it means when it “doesn’t work as expected” without knowing what is the expected behavior

Comment: @David S the #include <cs.50h> just gives me access to the get_string function!

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen So the Cipher of Vigenere is supposed to have a key as input, for example "abcd". This will decipher any plaintext, according to each character in the key, where a = 0 and b = 1 etc. So a key "abcd" with plaintext "aaaa" would give "abcd". if the plaintext is longer than the key, the key is supposed to loop back to [0] and start over until plaintext == '\0'

Comment: @AltijdGoed - misspelt vigenere if you’re quick

Comment: @AltijdGoed The problem can not be reproduced, I've entered **"bcda"** as input and my plain text was **"aaaaaaa"** and The program finished normally with the following: **"bcdabcd"**

Comment: @DavidS can you try an input of "baz" with "aaaaa"? For me that gives me an output of "bazbbbbb". I've found that if the first letter of the key is a 'b' followed by an 'a' it always bugs out

Comment: You should use character constants instead of numbers.

Comment: OT: it is very poor programming practice to access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected command line parameter

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error.\n");` 1)  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`   2)  when outputting a message about missing or incorrect command line parameters, it is typical to output a USAGE message, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s KeyText\n", argv[0] );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the *cipher* manipulation you are doing in your code can cause *j* to always zero and lead to first char being printed repeatedly.

this is caused due to the behaviour of the ***ascii -> non-ascii -> ascii***, which is the desired behaviour from the ciphering process

In order to fix the problem you need to use only the value of the *cipher* and not the manipulation on it in the condition.
What I did was copy the value to a different *pointer* and by so keeping the condition to refer to the original *char* of the original *cipher* using **malloc** and **memset**.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        char *input = argv[1];

        for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if (!isalpha(input[i]))
            {
                printf("Error.\n");
                return (1);
            }
        }
        char *plaintext = "aaaaaaa";
        char *cipher = argv[1];
        //<============================
        char *moving_cipher;
        moving_cipher = (char *) malloc(3);
        memcpy(moving_cipher, cipher, 3);
        //<============================
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int code = 0;

        while (plaintext[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (cipher[j] >= 97)
            {
                moving_cipher[j] = cipher[j] - 97;
            }
            if (isupper(cipher[j]))
            {
               moving_cipher[j] = cipher[j] - 65;
            }
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", 'a' + (plaintext[i] - 'a' + moving_cipher[j]) % 26);
                j++;
            }
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", 'A' + (plaintext[i] - 'A' + moving_cipher[j]) % 26);
                j++;
            }
            if (plaintext[i] == ' ')
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
            if (!isalpha(plaintext[i]) && !isspace(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
            if (cipher[j] == '\0' && plaintext[i] != ' ')
            {
                j = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return (0);
    }
```

Notice:
I checked in the problematic inputs as you wrote in your comments, this is why you need to find the desired size in a smart why and not hard coded.

**Input: "baz"**

**output before fix: "bazbbbb"**

**output after fix: "bazbazb"**

Comment: this answer does not compile!  The main reason is the statement: `#include <string.h>`  is missing for the function: `memcpy()`

Comment: @user3629249 Fixed the issue, although the main issue was the use of the  *memcpy* function, and the understanding that cipher changes due to the manipulations(this is who we need a copy for the ciphering and one, untouched, to use in the condition)

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. does not use the non-portable library `cs50`
2. properly outputs error info to `stderr`
3. performs the desired functionality
4. cleanly compiles

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s cypherKey\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    // implied else, user entered correct number of parameters

    char * cipher = argv[1];

    for (int i = 0; cipher[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha( cipher[i]))
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "key must be all alphabetic characters\n");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    // implied else, key all alphabetic characters

    char plaintext[1024];
    puts( "Please enter the plain text" );
    if( !fgets( plaintext, sizeof(plaintext), stdin ) )
    {
        perror( "fgets to input plain text failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //implied else, fgets successful

    // remove possible trailing newline
    plaintext[ strcspn( plaintext, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    printf("ciphertext: ");


    for( int j = 0, i = 0; plaintext[i]; i++ )
    {
        if (cipher[j] >= 97)
        {
            cipher[j] = (char)(cipher[j] - 97);
        }

        if (isupper(cipher[j]))
        {
           cipher[j] = (char)(cipher[j] - 65);
        }

        if (islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", 'a' + (plaintext[i] - 'a' + cipher[j]) % 26);
            j++;
        }

        if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", 'A' + (plaintext[i] - 'A' + cipher[j]) % 26);
            j++;
        }

        if (plaintext[i] == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }

        if (!isalpha(plaintext[i]) && !isspace(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }

        if (cipher[j] == '\0' && plaintext[i] != ' ')
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

The following are a couple of typical runs of the program

./untitled is the executable

```
./untitled
USAGE: ./untitled cypherKey

./untitled abcd
Please enter the plain text
This is a plain text message
ciphertext: Tikv it c slbkq tfzw mfuvahg

./untitled bcda
Please enter the plain text
This is a plain text message
ciphertext: Ujls ju d qndjp wfzw ngvtcjf
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you change the character in `cipher[j]` from being an ASCII code to an index into "ABC...XYZ" the following comparison doesn't work to detect the end of the key code:

```
if (cipher[j] == '\0' ...
```

An 'A' or 'a' will become the value 0 which is the same as '\0'. So it's not the leading 'b' but the following 'a' which causes the behavior.

Put this at a strategic place in the loop and you will see it instantly:

```
printf("%d %d %02X %02X\n", i, j, cipher[j], plaintext[i]);
```